# How to request microphone permission with Adobe (Harman) AIR MacOS app running on Big Sur

Tags: air, adobe, harman

Pre Big Sur the native MacOS microphone permission request alert would automatically appear when a Microphone object was created.

Running the app on Big Sur that is not the case.

Would anyone know how to initiate a MacOS permission prompt?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Details on how to fix this can be found here:

https://github.com/airsdk/Adobe-Runtime-Support/issues/532#issuecomment-779792767